# Error while overloading <<. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c++, function, class, io, operator-overloading

I am learning C++ and I am working on overloading <<. I am using the below code to print the time from class. It seems to be working with friend function but when I use without friend, it seems to be causing the error "**No match for operator<<**". What am I doing wrong here? Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

public:
    Time(int hh, int mm, int ss)
    {
        second = ss%60;
        mm +=ss/60;

        minute = mm%60;
        hh +=mm/60;

        hour = hh;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream &out);  //overloading << function declaration
};

ostream& Time::operator <<(ostream &out) // overloading << function definition
{
    out << "Time - " << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second;

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Time tm(10,36,60);
    cout << tm;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out);
```

defines `<<` such that the LHS is a `Time` object and RHS is a `std::ostream` object.

It can be used as:

```
Time tm(10,36,60);
tm << cout;
```

not as

```
cout << tm;
```

To use

```
cout << tm;
```

you need to define a function whose LHS is of type `std::ostream`. Hence, it cannot be a member function of `Time`.

Declare the function as:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Time const& ti);
```

and implement it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a member operator overload, the left-hand-side of the operator is the object of that class. So your member:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out);
```

actually will match usages:

```
tm << cout
```

but not `cout << tm`.

To fix this you should use a non-member function. My preferred way is:

```
// not inside a class definition
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Time const &tm)
{
    // output using public methods of tm

    return os;
}
```

However another common technique is to use a friend function:

```
// Inside Time's class definition
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Time const &tm)
{
    // output using private members of tm

    return os;
}
```

Note that even though the latter appears inside a class definition, it's actually not a member function. The `friend` keyword makes it so.

Comment: Oh... oops. I didn't see that. Upvoted in any case ;)